# SQL comparing two tables with common id but the id in table 2 could being in two different columns

Tags: sql

Given the following SQL tables:

Administrators:

```
id  Name   rating
 1  Jeff      48
 2  Albert    55
 3  Ken       35
 4  France    56
 5  Samantha  52
 6  Jeff      50
```

Meetings:

```
id   originatorid    Assitantid
1              3             5
2              6             3
3              1             2
4              6             4
```

I would like to generate a table from Ken's point of view (id=3) therefore his id could be possibly present in two different columns in the meetings' table. (The statement IN does not work since I introduce two different field columns).

Thus the ouput would be:

```
id   originatorid    Assitantid
1              3             5
2              6             3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really just need to see which column Ken's id is in, you only need an `OR`. The following will produce your example output exactly.

```
SELECT * FROM Meetings WHERE originatorid = 3 OR Assistantid = 3;
```

If you need to take the complex route and list names along with meetings, an `OR` in your join's `ON` clause should work here:

```
SELECT 
  Administrators.name,
  Administrators.id,
  Meetings.originatorid,
  Meetings.Assistantid
FROM Administrators
   JOIN Meetings 
     ON Administrators.id = Meetings.originatorid 
     OR Administrators.id = Meetings.Assistantid
Where Administrators.name = 'Ken'
```

Comment: I have a question though. Is there a way to use the "IN" selector combined with the OR? Not in this case.. but in the case that there is an additional table in the middle: Administrator+Meeting+Room (Just for learning purposes).

Comment: My comment is not clear I gonna have to ask another question for this I guess.

Comment: @user903645 `IN ()` is intended to compare one single column against multiple possible acceptable values. The only ways to force it into multiple columns would be to engage some tricky joins and UNION queries to convert the contents of multiple columns into one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will look further in that direction!